# Navigation bar items are not visible on real device

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

Today I added blur effect to `navigationBar`, which looks great. However the buttons inside `navigationBar` are only visible when I test the application on **simulator** but are hidden when I test it on real device(**iPhone 5s**). What could cause such a problem? I have no idea what causes this, maybe something is not in accordance with something?

I have two `tableviews` with navigation bar. I set the blur only in first view but it sets it also on the second view.

**Edit:** Inside first view all buttons are visible even on real device.

**Edit2**: All buttons are visible on real **iPhone 6 IOS 9.3.4** but not on real **iPhone 5s IOS 10 Beta 6**. **So the problem is only on IOS 10.**

**Edit3:** The button is not visible but it acts right(goes back to first controller)

Like this I set the blur effect and call it inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
func addBlurEffect(toView view:UIView?) {
        // Add blur view
        guard let view = view else { return }


        //This will let visualEffectView to work perfectly
        if let navBar = view as? UINavigationBar{
            navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
            navBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        }


        var bounds = view.bounds
        bounds.offsetInPlace(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)
        bounds.size.height = bounds.height + 20.0


        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)

        visualEffectView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        visualEffectView.frame = bounds
        visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        view.insertSubview(visualEffectView, atIndex: 0)

    }
```

Comment: Do you set images over bar items?

Comment: No. I forget to mention that on first view navbar items are visible.

Comment: Which device you are testing with.

Comment: I am testing it on real iPhone 5s.

Comment: can you clarify your problem?

Comment: when you call for cellForRowAtIndexPath for second table, hide the blur effect.. if tableview == secondTable { hideBlur() } and if tableView == firstTable { showBlur() }

Comment: It's weird that it appears on simulator. I would start to watch a difference between iOS version of a Simulator and real device iOS version.

Comment: @pedrouan ohh.. I forgot that I the iPhone 5s had the IOS 10 beta 6 but the iPhone 6 had 9.3.4.. So I think that is the problem but how to solve it then?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp Well this could be the point. What is the Xcode version you use? I bet it's something between 8 Beta 1 and Beta 3 ... ?

Comment: It is the last Xcode beta. And I tested on Simulator with IOS9 which worked and on simulator IOS10 it didn't. But the weird thing is one button IS visible.

Comment: Try to print(bounds) after 'var bounds line and after 'bounds.size.height' line. New SDK could access frame property in different ways. But you say, your Xcode is latest Beta 6? Are you sure? I am surprised, your - for example - 'forBarMetrics: .Default' is not 'forBarMetrics: .default'. In two latest editions, all these properties are lowercased.

Comment: I opened your code on Xcode 8 Beta 6 and it is invalid. So update your Xcode first, when deploying on your iOS 10 Beta 6 machine. http://pasteboard.co/cuywYuFwp.png There are releasing their iOS version much different beta to beta throughout the summer

Comment: I am writing on Swift 2.3 not 3. Those errors you got is because you use swift 3. And those are syntax errors.